# mvc3 partial view error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, combobox, partial-views

I want to make a form for entering customer data. It consists of several text boxes and a combobox. And it is the whole problem lies in this combobox. When I trying to render this partialview , gets error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

This is partialview controller code

```
public PartialViewResult GetStates()
        {
            var states = from s in conn.order_data select s.state;
            return PartialView(states.ToList());
        }
```

GetStates partialview

```
@model IEnumerable<bookstore.state>

@foreach (var item in Model) {

    <select>
    <option>@item.STATE_Name</option>
    </select>
}
```

part of main view

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("GetStates");}
 </div>
```

Please, help

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are loading the view dynamically (in which case you could do it with jquery get)
here is how you could do it

Controller:

```
public ActionMethod MainView()
{
  var model = new myMainModel { States = from s in conn.order_data select s.state };
  return View()
}
```

Main View:

```
@Html.Partial("MyPartialViewName", Model.States);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(states != null)
{
  return PartialView(states.ToList());
}

return PartialView();
```